# Impose an empty frame as a replacement for an image

Tags: html

How can I force an empty frame of specified size in html if an image is not found ? for example, suppose I have an image i know to be 100x100, but the image is not found at the specified url. yet, I would still like to have an empty frame 100x100.

I tried setting `<img src="whatever" width="100" height="100" />`, as well as via css,  but it does not work. if the image is not found, nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the css property `display: inline-block` to the image. If you need to support older browsers, then you need to use block instead of inline-block.